# How To Read an Elasticsearch Snapshot

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I would like to copy the contents of my elasticsearch cluster to my data lake for joining purposes. Currently I am doing this buy scanning the entire index every hour and building a new set of parquets from them. This process is slow, expensive, and hard on the cluster while **scraping** is in progress.

I'm assuming it's easier for elasticsearch to create snapshots then it is to have dozens of clients making scan calls in parallel. So i'd like to make a snapshot of the index, split it horizontally among many workers, and have those workers produce parquets.

The issue is that my cluster is hosted by aws's elasticsearch service, which does not provide plaintext snapshots. I don't know how to read the standard snapshot format without loading it into another elasticsearch cluster. I'd like to be able to read the snapshot from a light python or java process in a horizontally scaling worker pool.

Is it possible to read an elasticsearch snapshot without loading it into elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

es snapshot , read must load data, you can also copy data file to a new es's data path, es can auto load data

```
PUT _snapshot/my_backup 
{
    "type": "fs", 
    "settings": {
        "location": "/mount/backups/my_backup" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the elasticsearch service provided by aws doesn't support `fs` type snapshots. Only `s3`

Comment: @micah copy your es data to service, del .lock file in data, del .kibana index if have, and restart your service, es will auto load data